# How to disable UIWebView refreshing?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have made an app that contains a lot of PDF files that are loaded in the `UIWebView`.

Whenever I open the PDF, close it, and then go back to it, the file starts from the top again, it reloads. I don't want it to reload once the user goes out of the file and comes back to it. Can someone help with the code for it to stop refreshing and where I should insert it?

The code I use is down below. Can someone tell me what's wrong with it, and what I should do so it doesn't refresh again?

```
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2



- (void)viewDidLoad

    {


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HnonC" ofType:@"pdf"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [Webview loadRequest:request];
        [Webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save vertical offset of scrollview before close it:

```
 int pageYOffset = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:pageYOffset forKey:@"YOFFSET"];
```

And when webView did load scroll to saved offset

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wv {

int pageYOffset = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"YOFFSET"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"window.scrollTo(0, %d);",pageYOffset]];
}
```

And don't forget to set webview.delegate = self;